# java 8 lambda expression support for glass-fish server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lambda, java-ee-7

I m trying to use lambda expressions inside jsp script-let. But I gives me following error.

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I'm using:

- Source/Binary Format = JDK 8
- Java EE 7
- glass-fish server 4.1
- IDE - NETBEANS

Any suggestions to get rid of this error would be appreciable.

Comment: `"(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions) "` you need java 8, does you project point to jdk8 ?

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/fixing-glassfish-jdk-path-problem-solved

Comment: @RaphaelRoth  I made the changes but still no luck... :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set JSP compiler source, which can be done in glassfish-web.xml.

```
<jsp-config>
    <property name="compilerSourceVM" value="8"/>
    <property name="compilerTargetVM" value="8"/>
</jsp-config>
```

But for me it isn't final solution, because after change compiler source, server write: JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP.